# SQL joins with an aggregation

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables - `product` and `product_features`.

I need to grab all products and display each of their number of feature. Please help.

Comment: When you want to join the least you could show us is the relationship between the two tables :)

Comment: Products has id and product features has id and product_id

Comment: @user1989032 - Add that info to your question and give as much info as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT( pf.id )
FROM prod p
LEFT JOIN prod_feat pf
ON p.id = pf.prod_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: I like making up column names too.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the product id, you don't need to do a join:

```
select pf.prod_id, count(*) as NumFeatures
from prod_feat pf
group by pf.prod_id
```